# How can I run various tests for Quarkus Kafka Stream with Testcontainer?

Tags: testing, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, quarkus, testcontainers

Following the steps described here https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#testing-using-a-kafka-broker it's possible to define quarkus tests using a "real" Kafka broker.

`@QuarkusTest` instantiate all the resources needed, including `KafkaStrems` and during the individual tests (`@Test`) we can limit ourselves to produce records for input topics and consume results from output topics.

The current stream `Topology` include steps of groupBy, aggregation, join, ...
During test, the problem is that, after first one, all other tests have "dirty aggregates". A `kafkaStreams.cleanUp()` might solve the problem but produce an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot clean up while running.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.cleanUp(KafkaStreams.java:1486)
    at eu.reply.lea.visibility.unieuro.stream.TopologyProducerIT.setup(TopologyProducerIT.java:70)
    at eu.reply.lea.visibility.unieuro.stream.TopologyProducerIT_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at eu.reply.lea.visibility.unieuro.stream.TopologyProducerIT_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
    at eu.reply.lea.visibility.unieuro.stream.TopologyProducerIT_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.getBeanInstance(InstanceImpl.java:225)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.getInternal(InstanceImpl.java:211)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:97)
    ... 73 more
```

The question is: what is the correct approch to run KafkaStream testing in quarkus (the "traditional" approach of: perform a test, perform rollback and continue with the next ones seems not applicable).

Also the following approach fails:

```
        // test 1
        kafkaStreams.close();
        kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
        kafkaStreams.start();
        // test 2
        kafkaStreams.close();
        kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
        kafkaStreams.start();
        // ...
```